# Loading in HTML for smaller screens

Tags: html, media-queries

I know you can load in a different CSS sheet with Media Queries, but what if there is a bunch of content and dozens of divs you do not want to show at all on smaller devices. Is there a way just to load in an entirely different set of HTML for very simple mobile pages, when you have a very complex design for larger devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea will be making the page suitable for small devices, then load extra content with the help of javascript

Comment: That is definitely a good idea! What I ended up doing was nesting all the objects I wanted to show only on a mobile device in a class called "mobile". I set, using Media Queries, all divs to a display:none property (under the mobile query) and then did the same bit for: div.mobile {display:none} for all larger devices.

Comment: But the thing is when you the page is loaded all elements will be loaded/downloaded. Setting things display:none only make them not visible but they are actually using the bandwidth. It's ok for page without too much content but if you have lots of images you should avoid this practise

Answer (score 0):

Try to learn some of Responsible websites. Frameworks like Bootstrap already use what your looking for.